# predict 2 dimension output from 10 numbers by tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I want to predict one number from 10 numbers

What I want to do is predict `t` from `mat`

Each `mat[i]` is corrsponding to `t[i]`

Of course I have more then 5 rows in mat and t , just simplifies the problem now.

I have written the code like this below.

```
#There is target data `t` and traindata `mat[0]`,`mat[1]`,`mat[2]`....

t = [0,1,0,1,0] #answer 2 dimension

limit = 10# number of degrees
mat = [[2,-2,3,-4,2,2,3,5,3,6],   #10 degrees number of mat[0] leads t[0]
[1,3,-3,2,2,5,1,3,2,3],   #10 degrees number of mat[1] leads t[1]
[-2,3,2,-2,2,-2,1,3,4,5],   #10 degrees number of mat[2] leads t[2]
[-2,2,-1,-2,2,-2,7,3,9,2],   #10 degrees number of mat[3] leads t[3]
[-2,-3,2,-2,2,-4,1,-4,4,5],   #10 degrees number of mat[4] leads t[4]
]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,5]))
y = tf.matmul(x,w)
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y-t))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

train_t = np.array(mat)
train_t = train_t.reshape([limit,5])
train_x = np.zeros([limit,5])

# initialize
for row, num in enumerate(range(1,limit + 1)):
    for col, n in enumerate(range(0,5)):
        train_x[row][col] = num**n

i = 0
for _ in range(100000):
    i += 1
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:train_x,t:train_t})
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        loss_val = sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x:train_x,t:train_t})
        print('step : %d,Loss: %f' % (i,loss_val))
        w_val = sess.run(w)
        pprint("w_val")
        pprint(w_val)
```

However this shows error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wisdom2.py", line 60, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:train_x,t:train_t})
  File "/Users/whitebear/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/whitebear/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 975, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 5) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shape of your placeholder and the shape of your input do not match. The placeholder `x` expects a value with *N* rows and 10 columns, but `train_x` has 10 rows and 5 columns. Likewise, `t` should have `N` rows and 1 column, but the passed value `train_t` has 10 rows and 5 columns. You should either change the shape of your placeholders or the shape of your inputs.